# Code to search a list with a VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm trying to create a userform in VBA that will search a list in another sheet and display all matching results, is it also possible to have that data displayed by default to then be narrowed down by the search box value?

There are three columns in the list it will search, but if it finds a match, ideally it would display the data from the first and third, the middle column is irrelevant, but needs to stay for other code.

Then you might need to select one of the results to display it in a specific folder in the workbook (column one result in one cell, column two in the cell next to it).

I'm completely new to userforms so a task like this is quite daunting, I'm not even certain how to activate the form from the sheet.

Any feedback is appreciated, I'll comment any useful code I find online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished most of what I was after with the following:

```
    Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Employees").Visible = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Employees").Activate
    Employee = EmployeeName.Value
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=*" & Employee & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Temp").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Temp").Range("A1:AFD1000000").ClearContents

    'validation to stop the form breaking if a nane is searched that doesnt exist
    Range("A1000000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "KeyID" Then GoTo validationend

    'Take the data that has been filtered by employee name and store it in a temp worksheet
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Temp").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Delete any data that is irrelevant at this stage
    Range("D:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("G:AZ").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Temp")
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.ListBox.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

validationend:
    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Activate

    'Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Temp").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    'Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Employees").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Error: Name not found. Please check your spelling and try again.")

    Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Form").Activate

    'Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Temp").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    'Workbooks("Form1.xlsm").Worksheets("Employees").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Doesn't work perfectly, so if you want more answers, I'll be asking relevant questions soon.